# Removal Directive from UK in 2013; can I return for a visit?

Tags: uk, removal

I received a removal directive from the UK in July 2013 and had government assistance in returning to my country (I didn't buy the ticket myself).

Now, I want to apply for visit visa for myself and my family. Am I ineligible to apply for a visitor, or any other kind, of visa to enter the UK?

Comment: It would likely help to know why you were removed from the UK three years ago.

Comment: > received travel ticket from UK goverment -- what does this mean, there's no such legal entity as "UK government", who bought you a ticket and for what reason? Voting to close as unclear until at least these two questions are cleaned up.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit, to improve the chance of a response. Should I have misunderstood, or altered, your meaning, you can undo/roll back the changes.

Comment: @chx Are you making all this fuss because the OP could not name the specific department or used the phrase “UK government” instead of “British government”? It was either [a voluntary return](https://www.gov.uk/return-home-voluntarily/voluntary-return) or an assisted return and is arranged by the Home Office, like everything removal-related. A few additional details might be useful but the question is not particularly unclear. Other countries have similar programs incidentally, nothing surprising here…

Comment: @chx he means he was removed using public funds, i.e., taxpayer's expense. It usually means it was an inland enforcement operation rather than a portside removal.  Either way he's not going to be back.

Comment: You are allowed to apply, but the chances of being approved are approximately zero.

Comment: See also http://i.stack.imgur.com/sRvre.jpg

Comment: @Relaxed name-calling comment edited, rather than deleted as it was flagged.  Please don't resort to ad-hominem.

Comment: @MarkMayo It wasn't name calling as much as a genuine question: Does chx know this or not? And I don't find that question particularly aggressive given that (1) it's pretty basic stuff as far as I am concerned and (2) he was himself passing judgment in a rather aggressive way based on what seems to be, whether you like it or not, ignorance.

Answer (score 7):

**Am I ineligible to apply for a visitor, or any other kind, of visa to enter the UK?**

No. As I understand it, anybody can apply at any time and as often as they see fit.

However some of the fees are quite substantial and since in your case the chances of being granted a visa are so low you might as well save yourself filling in forms and just set fire to your money.

Comment: +1, the fee is £85. Not a back-breaker, but your point is taken nonetheless.

Comment: @pnuts didn't that kick in from today? Or anyway, thanks for the head's up