# My visa was cancelled at the airport

Tags: visas, uk, airports, cancellations

I got this inside my passport on getting back to my country... Its says

> REMOVAL DIRECTIONS
>
> I hereby direct you to remove¹/ make arrangements for the removal² of
>   the person named above from the United Kingdom to Nigeria by so so
>   flight connecting to lage..
>
> I hereby inform you that I intend to direct you remove¹ or make
>   arrangements for the remove² of the person named above from the United
>   Kingdom. You will be informed of such directions as soon as possible..
>
> If a decision is taken to cancel these directions/this notice of
>   intention to remov, you will be notified immediately. If no directions
>   have been given by 28 February 2020, the situation will be reviewed.
>   If you contact this office you will be informed of the outcome, and
>   any necessary further review can then be arranged.

I don't understand this view .. Have I been banned from UK? Or what can I do to know my standing?

Comment: Pretty sure a lot more happened than just getting a stamp in your passport, especially since there is no exit passport control in the UK, this cannot have been added "when getting back to your country", it is probably quite the opposite. A detailed description of what happened would help in trying to determine your possible courses of action (if any).

Comment: @Idowu If you weren’t informed of a ban at the time, a removal typically means you’d be refused a visa on either mandatory or discretionary grounds for a period of between 2 to 10 years https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/673999/GGFR-Section-2-v29.0EXT.PDF

Comment: That is not a stamp, it is an extract from 'Removal Directions' which are served on the relevant airline. The Odd "1" or "2" in the text along with the / symbol are options and the Officer should have deleted or redacted the option that did not apply.

Comment: In what form was the quoted text in your passport?  Was it stuck in firmly on a bit of paper with a stamp, was it tucked in on a bit of loose paper etc etc etc?  When did you get your passport back? Before boarding?  Were you given it on arrival at the destination upon exiting hte aircraft?  The answers to these questions will go a long way to allowing people to give you a good answer.

Comment: To hazard a guess (and I could be very wrong here), you were handed your passport either on entry to the aircraft or upon exiting the aircraft, and the quoted notice was tucked in to it on a loose bit of paper - that indicates to me that it was accidentally handed to you, and was either intended for the airline to retain or was never intended to be used.

Answer (score 6):

> Have I been banned into UK. Or  ...

I think you have been "Removed from" the UK. If you paid for your own return flight it might be regarded as leaving voluntarily even though the immigration officer issued a removal notice. If the airline was forced to return you to your home country at their own cost I guess this means you were removed. You might need to explain more or consult a UK lawyer to be certain (but see below).

This removal notice will affect future visa requests by you. See:

- [Removal Directive from UK in 2013; can I return for a visit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/81691/13639)

If you were banned, I believe you would have received a paper document saying so.

See

- [US Citizen overstayed visit to UK, left voluntarily, does she have a 1 year ban?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/79571/13639)

> wat can I do to knw my stand

You may be able to make a [Subject Access Request](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration/request-personal-information-held-by-uk-visas-and-immigration)

See

- [How do i find out how long my uk ban is?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/132068/13639)